# WordPress плагин wp-recall

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин

Подскажите, пожалуйста, по поводу плагина wp-recall. Хочу убрать вкладку регистрации, чтобы только можно было авторизироваться, но не могу найти, где именно это можно сделать.

Comment: Убрать  код      <div class="form_head">
        <div class="form_auth form_active"><?php _e('Authorization','wp-recall'); ?></div>
        <?php if(rcl_is_register_open()): ?>
            <div class="form_reg"><?php if(!$typeform){ ?><a href="#" class="link-register-rcl link-tab-rcl "><?php _e('Registration','wp-recall'); ?></a><?php } ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div> по  пути  wp-content\plugins\wp-recall\templates\form-sign

Comment: просто отключите регистрацию через настройки сайта